# Rhomobile how to edit the Android Manifest

Tags: android, rhomobile, rhodes

I am having difficulty changing the AndroidManifest.xml file.

"C:\RhoStudio\ruby\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\rhodes-3.2.2\platform\android\Rhodes\AndroidManifest.xml"

I am trying to add the following to the manifest for the build to allow me to save files to the SD card:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I add it but then when I build, the line does **not** appear in the AndroidManifest.xml that is outputted into the bin/tmp folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:
  capabilities:
    - sdcard
```

Adding the following to the build.yml adds the above the AndroidManifest.xml and allows me to read/write to the SDcard.