# How to restrict Android app for mobile using Rhomobile

Tags: android, rhomobile

I want my Android application in google market to be listed only for android mobile and not for tablet. i use rhomobile to develop the application. please help me

Answer (score 1):

You have to play with this settings in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<supports-screens
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="false"
android:xlargeScreens="false"/>
```

You can use this too for better filtering:

```
<compatible-screens>

    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Comment: i dont use native.i am using rhomobile cross platform tool

Comment: that has a settings which will generate this. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHansetApps check your rhomobile what you need to set and where to have this generated. Like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13372445/529543